# JQuery Disable Submit Call

Tags: jquery

I have asked this question: [Using JQuery to Disable Submit button and/or get Value of form action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105944/using-jquery-to-disable-submit-button-and-or-get-value-of-form-action)

But possibly didn't explain myself correctly. I don't necessarily want to disable the submit button. What I want to do is, when this button is clicked I want to make a call and pass information to a pop up dialog. When the dialog appears it has a yes/no choice. When the user clicks yes/no it comes back and fires the original button command to continue to the next step of the checkout process.

But here is my problem, I have to use the class names to drill down to get to this button because there are other forms on this page that use the same button to continue on and so forth.

So I want to be able to start from the top div and work down the the continue button at the bottom. Then I want to make a call out to my modal dialog. The problem I have is I can't even get an alert box to pop up AND when I click the button it submits the information and goes on to the next step.

Sorry for the repeat to post to my original question, but I am not getting any play off of it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `onsubmit` to your form, and then use a function with a `confirm` dialog, like this:

[**Demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/yahfL/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to submit this form?");
});
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid modifying the form because this is going to be a plugin. So when it's installed I would like to have the user do as little coding as possible.

Comment: @sjramsay I've edited answer, so you are not going to ask the user to change his code! The jquery code works without changing the original form.

Comment: In the code that I originally provided, you will see one of the top div's has something like 'select-shipping-address" class. On this same page, before this form, there will be a form for select-billing-address class with the same button name and class.So I don't want to stop that button from being clicked. I want the user to select the billing address, go forward to the shipping section and when they enter in the shipping info in that form that it gets intercepted first. Is there a way to intercept that submit button starting at the top most div so I know I am in that div with the form?Thanks

Comment: Okay. Toni. I got it. I just put the class name of the div in front of the 'form' and it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually one last thing. When I did what you had, with the confirm box it worked, but now that I have my code in to pop up a modal window, it just by passes the modal and acts like it was submitted.

Comment: Toni, my dialog comes up. I click, "yes" it closes, but when I click the button again, the dialog comes up again. which is to be expected. if I programmatically do the submitting of the form, same thing. how do I get around moving to the next step now here?

Comment: Hi @sjramsay you can work around that by using a simple flag variable ... if need help about that you can show me your code and I'll be glad to help you!